# Display a list of users by number of closed/deleted posts

Tags: feature-request

Moderators have access to a list of users by number of flags (of any kind) against their posts. Going by the general rule of thumb that `more_flags == low_quality_poster`, this feature is usually helpful on beta sites (where many users don't have close privileges and flag instead) and on large sites where there's a lot of flag volume for this sorting to make sense.

However, on *Mathematica*.SE, we have a lot of 3k+ users (for our age), many of whom came from Stack Overflow, and are knowledgable about the tools available to them. These folks use the tools exactly as designed and resort to downvoting + commenting + closing posts that need to be, instead of flagging. Unfortunately, this also means that this list of flagged users is not very helpful, as the actual low quality posters don't have very many flags against them (but have a lot of closed and/or deleted posts) and the list is populated by mostly benign users (for one time NaA flag pileup) and top users (for the automatic too many comments posted flags).

**Now I don't want our users to change their behavior and start flagging when it's not necessary**, but I would like that mod page to also list users by number of closed/deleted posts and downvotes (incl. deleted) on their posts (all time and last 30 days), which is a far better indicator of low quality than flags.

Comment: This is a good idea even for other sites with less-experienced users, such as the sites I moderate. I have noticed that on those sites some of our most reputable and active users have also collected the most flags (for various reasons), rendering the flag count an unreliable indicator of (bad) quality. The users that cause me the most worry are those where more than half their posts have been closed, deleted, or migrated; tools for tracking them based on these counts or proportions would indeed be useful.